# ESP32TimerInterrupt - unsolved variables (missing inclusion?)

Tags: timer, interrupt, esp32

I'm testing the library ***ESP32TimerInterrupt***  for ESP32 using the example ISR_16_Timars_Array. While compiling I get errors of missing declarations about the method timer_isr_callback_add and the parameters ***TIMER_INTR_T0*** and ***TIMER_INTR_T1***. Although all the h files included with the library are available to the example, I assume I miss some file inclusion - which one?
And another question - I'm using the board Heltec WiFILoRa 32(V2). To minimize interference with other HW/SW features I prefer using timer 2 - is it possible?
Best regards
Yons Gy

The error messages:

```
Arduino: 1.8.19 (Windows 10), Board: "WiFi LoRa 32(V2), Disabled, 240MHz (WiFi/BT), 921600, None, REGION_EU868, None"
In file included from D:\Current\Tractor\TractorSW\motion\src\ISR_16_Timers_Array\ISR_16_Timers_Array.ino:23:0:
D:\Current\Tractor\TractorSW\motion\src\ISR_16_Timers_Array\ESP32TimerInterrupt.hpp: In member function 'bool ESP32TimerInterrupt::setFrequency(const float&, bool (* const&)(void*))':
ESP32TimerInterrupt.hpp:329:100: error: 'timer_isr_callback_add' was not declared in this scope
         timer_isr_callback_add(_timerGroup, _timerIndex, _callback, (void *) (uint32_t) _timerNo, 0);
                                                                                                    ^
D:\Current\Tractor\TractorSW\motion\src\ISR_16_Timers_Array\ESP32TimerInterrupt.hpp: In member function 'void ESP32TimerInterrupt::detachInterrupt()':
ESP32TimerInterrupt.hpp:371:66: error: 'TIMER_INTR_T0' was not declared in this scope
       timer_group_intr_disable(_timerGroup, (_timerIndex == 0) ? TIMER_INTR_T0 : TIMER_INTR_T1);
                                                                  ^
ESP32TimerInterrupt.hpp:371:82: error: 'TIMER_INTR_T1' was not declared in this scope
       timer_group_intr_disable(_timerGroup, (_timerIndex == 0) ? TIMER_INTR_T0 : TIMER_INTR_T1);
                                                                                  ^
D:\Current\Tractor\TractorSW\motion\src\ISR_16_Timers_Array\ESP32TimerInterrupt.hpp: In member function 'void ESP32TimerInterrupt::disableTimer()':
ESP32TimerInterrupt.hpp:380:66: error: 'TIMER_INTR_T0' was not declared in this scope
       timer_group_intr_disable(_timerGroup, (_timerIndex == 0) ? TIMER_INTR_T0 : TIMER_INTR_T1);
                                                                  ^
ESP32TimerInterrupt.hpp:380:82: error: 'TIMER_INTR_T1' was not declared in this scope
       timer_group_intr_disable(_timerGroup, (_timerIndex == 0) ? TIMER_INTR_T0 : TIMER_INTR_T1);
                                                                                  ^
D:\Current\Tractor\TractorSW\motion\src\ISR_16_Timers_Array\ESP32TimerInterrupt.hpp: In member function 'void ESP32TimerInterrupt::reattachInterrupt()':
ESP32TimerInterrupt.hpp:390:65: error: 'TIMER_INTR_T0' was not declared in this scope
       timer_group_intr_enable(_timerGroup, (_timerIndex == 0) ? TIMER_INTR_T0 : TIMER_INTR_T1);
                                                                 ^
ESP32TimerInterrupt.hpp:390:81: error: 'TIMER_INTR_T1' was not declared in this scope
       timer_group_intr_enable(_timerGroup, (_timerIndex == 0) ? TIMER_INTR_T0 : TIMER_INTR_T1);
                                                                                 ^
D:\Current\Tractor\TractorSW\motion\src\ISR_16_Timers_Array\ESP32TimerInterrupt.hpp: In member function 'void ESP32TimerInterrupt::enableTimer()':
ESP32TimerInterrupt.hpp:400:65: error: 'TIMER_INTR_T0' was not declared in this scope
       timer_group_intr_enable(_timerGroup, (_timerIndex == 0) ? TIMER_INTR_T0 : TIMER_INTR_T1);
                                                                 ^
ESP32TimerInterrupt.hpp:400:81: error: 'TIMER_INTR_T1' was not declared in this scope
       timer_group_intr_enable(_timerGroup, (_timerIndex == 0) ? TIMER_INTR_T0 : TIMER_INTR_T1);
                                                                                 ^
exit status 1
'timer_isr_callback_add' was not declared in this scope
```

The code (first - ESP32TimerInterrupt.hpp - library file), then the .ino file:
/****************************************************************************************************************************
ESP32TimerInterrupt.hpp
For ESP32, ESP32_S2, ESP32_S3, ESP32_C3 boards with ESP32 core v2.0.2+
Written by Khoi Hoang

```
  Built by Khoi Hoang https://github.com/khoih-prog/ESP32TimerInterrupt
  Licensed under MIT license

  The ESP32, ESP32_S2, ESP32_S3, ESP32_C3 have two timer groups, TIMER_GROUP_0 and TIMER_GROUP_1
  1) each group of ESP32, ESP32_S2, ESP32_S3 has two general purpose hardware timers, TIMER_0 and TIMER_1
  2) each group of ESP32_C3 has ony one general purpose hardware timer, TIMER_0
  
  All the timers are based on 64-bit counters (except 54-bit counter for ESP32_S3 counter) and 16 bit prescalers. 
  The timer counters can be configured to count up or down and support automatic reload and software reload. 
  They can also generate alarms when they reach a specific value, defined by the software. 
  The value of the counter can be read by the software program.

  Now even you use all these new 16 ISR-based timers,with their maximum interval practically unlimited (limited only by
  unsigned long miliseconds), you just consume only one ESP32-S2 timer and avoid conflicting with other cores' tasks.
  The accuracy is nearly perfect compared to software timers. The most important feature is they're ISR-based timers
  Therefore, their executions are not blocked by bad-behaving functions / tasks.
  This important feature is absolutely necessary for mission-critical tasks.

  Based on SimpleTimer - A timer library for Arduino.
  Author: mromani@ottotecnica.com
  Copyright (c) 2010 OTTOTECNICA Italy

  Based on BlynkTimer.h
  Author: Volodymyr Shymanskyy

  Version: 2.0.1
  
  Version Modified By   Date      Comments
  ------- -----------  ---------- -----------
  1.0.0   K Hoang      23/11/2019 Initial coding
  1.0.1   K Hoang      27/11/2019 No v1.0.1. Bump up to 1.0.2 to match ESP8266_ISR_TimerInterupt library
  1.0.2   K.Hoang      03/12/2019 Permit up to 16 super-long-time, super-accurate ISR-based timers to avoid being blocked
  1.0.3   K.Hoang      17/05/2020 Restructure code. Add examples. Enhance README.
  1.1.0   K.Hoang      27/10/2020 Restore cpp code besides Impl.h code to use if Multiple-Definition linker error.
  1.1.1   K.Hoang      06/12/2020 Add Version String and Change_Interval example to show how to change TimerInterval
  1.2.0   K.Hoang      08/01/2021 Add better debug feature. Optimize code and examples to reduce RAM usage
  1.3.0   K.Hoang      06/05/2021 Add support to ESP32-S2
  1.4.0   K.Hoang      01/06/2021 Add complex examples. Fix compiler errors due to conflict to some libraries.
  1.4.1   K.Hoang      14/11/2021 Avoid using D1 in examples due to issue with core v2.0.0 and v2.0.1
  1.5.0   K.Hoang      18/01/2022 Fix `multiple-definitions` linker error
  2.0.0   K Hoang      13/02/2022 Add support to new ESP32-S3. Restructure library.
  2.0.1   K Hoang      13/03/2022 Add example to demo how to use one-shot ISR-based timers. Optimize code
*****************************************************************************************************************************/

#pragma once

#ifndef ESP32TIMERINTERRUPT_HPP
#define ESP32TIMERINTERRUPT_HPP

#if ( ARDUINO_ESP32S2_DEV || ARDUINO_FEATHERS2 || ARDUINO_ESP32S2_THING_PLUS || ARDUINO_MICROS2 || \
        ARDUINO_METRO_ESP32S2 || ARDUINO_MAGTAG29_ESP32S2 || ARDUINO_FUNHOUSE_ESP32S2 || \
        ARDUINO_ADAFRUIT_FEATHER_ESP32S2_NOPSRAM )
  #define USING_ESP32_S2_TIMERINTERRUPT         true
#elif ( defined(ARDUINO_ESP32S3_DEV) || defined(ARDUINO_ESP32_S3_BOX) || defined(ARDUINO_TINYS3) || \
        defined(ARDUINO_PROS3) || defined(ARDUINO_FEATHERS3) )
  #define USING_ESP32_S3_TIMERINTERRUPT         true
#elif ( ARDUINO_ESP32C3_DEV )
  #define USING_ESP32_C3_TIMERINTERRUPT         true  
#elif defined(ESP32)
  #define USING_ESP32_TIMERINTERRUPT            true  
#else
  #error This code is intended to run on the ESP32 platform! Please check your Tools->Board setting.  
#endif

#ifndef ESP32_TIMER_INTERRUPT_VERSION
  #define ESP32_TIMER_INTERRUPT_VERSION          "ESP32TimerInterrupt v2.0.1"
  
  #define ESP32_TIMER_INTERRUPT_VERSION_MAJOR     2
  #define ESP32_TIMER_INTERRUPT_VERSION_MINOR     0
  #define ESP32_TIMER_INTERRUPT_VERSION_PATCH     1

  #define ESP32_TIMER_INTERRUPT_VERSION_INT      2000001
#endif

#ifndef TIMER_INTERRUPT_DEBUG
  #define TIMER_INTERRUPT_DEBUG      0
#endif

#if defined(ARDUINO)
  #if ARDUINO >= 100
    #include <Arduino.h>
  #else
    #include <WProgram.h>
  #endif
#endif

#include "TimerInterrupt_Generic_Debug.h"
#include <driver/timer.h>
#include "SimpleTimer.h"              // https://github.com/jfturcot/SimpleTimer

/*
  //ESP32 core v1.0.6, hw_timer_t defined in esp32/tools/sdk/include/driver/driver/timer.h:

  #define TIMER_BASE_CLK   (APB_CLK_FREQ)  //Frequency of the clock on the input of the timer groups 


 //@brief Selects a Timer-Group out of 2 available groups
 
typedef enum
{
  TIMER_GROUP_0 = 0, //!<Hw timer group 0
  TIMER_GROUP_1 = 1, //!<Hw timer group 1
  TIMER_GROUP_MAX,
} timer_group_t;


 //@brief Select a hardware timer from timer groups
 
typedef enum 
{
  TIMER_0 = 0, //!<Select timer0 of GROUPx
  TIMER_1 = 1, //!<Select timer1 of GROUPx
  TIMER_MAX,
} timer_idx_t;


 //@brief Decides the direction of counter
 
typedef enum 
{
  TIMER_COUNT_DOWN = 0, //Descending Count from cnt.high|cnt.low
  TIMER_COUNT_UP = 1,   //Ascending Count from Zero
  TIMER_COUNT_MAX
} timer_count_dir_t;


 //@brief Decides whether timer is on or paused
 
typedef enum 
{
  TIMER_PAUSE = 0,      //Pause timer counter
  TIMER_START = 1,      //Start timer counter
} timer_start_t;


 //@brief Decides whether to enable alarm mode
 
typedef enum 
{
  TIMER_ALARM_DIS = 0,  //Disable timer alarm
  TIMER_ALARM_EN = 1,   //Enable timer alarm
  TIMER_ALARM_MAX
} timer_alarm_t;


 //@brief Select interrupt type if running in alarm mode.
 
typedef enum 
{
  TIMER_INTR_LEVEL = 0,  //Interrupt mode: level mode
  //TIMER_INTR_EDGE = 1, //Interrupt mode: edge mode, Not supported Now
  TIMER_INTR_MAX
} timer_intr_mode_t;


 //@brief Select if Alarm needs to be loaded by software or automatically reload by hardware.
 
typedef enum 
{
  TIMER_AUTORELOAD_DIS = 0,  //Disable auto-reload: hardware will not load counter value after an alarm event
  TIMER_AUTORELOAD_EN = 1,   //Enable auto-reload: hardware will load counter value after an alarm event
  TIMER_AUTORELOAD_MAX,
} timer_autoreload_t;


 //@brief Data structure with timer's configuration settings
 
typedef struct 
{
  bool alarm_en;                    //Timer alarm enable 
  bool counter_en;                  //Counter enable 
  timer_intr_mode_t intr_type;      //Interrupt mode 
  timer_count_dir_t counter_dir;    //Counter direction  
  bool auto_reload;                 //Timer auto-reload 
  uint32_t divider;                 //Counter clock divider. The divider's range is from from 2 to 65536. 
} timer_config_t;

*/

class ESP32TimerInterrupt;

typedef ESP32TimerInterrupt ESP32Timer;

#if USING_ESP32_C3_TIMERINTERRUPT
  #define MAX_ESP32_NUM_TIMERS      2
#else
  #define MAX_ESP32_NUM_TIMERS      4
#endif

#define TIMER_DIVIDER             80                                //  Hardware timer clock divider
// TIMER_BASE_CLK = APB_CLK_FREQ = Frequency of the clock on the input of the timer groups
#define TIMER_SCALE               (TIMER_BASE_CLK / TIMER_DIVIDER)  // convert counter value to seconds


// In esp32/1.0.6/tools/sdk/esp32s2/include/driver/include/driver/timer.h
// typedef bool (*timer_isr_t)(void *);
//esp_err_t timer_isr_callback_add(timer_group_t group_num, timer_idx_t timer_num, timer_isr_t isr_handler, void *arg, int intr_alloc_flags);
//esp_err_t timer_isr_callback_remove(timer_group_t group_num, timer_idx_t timer_num);
//timer_deinit(timer_group_t group_num, timer_idx_t timer_num);
//esp_err_t timer_group_intr_enable(timer_group_t group_num, timer_intr_t intr_mask);
//esp_err_t timer_group_intr_disable(timer_group_t group_num, timer_intr_t intr_mask);

typedef bool (*esp32_timer_callback)  (void *);

// For ESP32_C3, TIMER_MAX == 1
// For ESP32 and ESP32_S2, TIMER_MAX == 2

typedef struct
{
  timer_idx_t         timer_idx;
  timer_group_t       timer_group;
  //int                 alarm_interval;
  //timer_autoreload_t  auto_reload;
} timer_info_t;

class ESP32TimerInterrupt
{
  private:
  
    timer_config_t stdConfig = 
    {
      .alarm_en     = TIMER_ALARM_EN,       //enable timer alarm
      .counter_en   = TIMER_START,          //starts counting counter once timer_init called
      .intr_type    = TIMER_INTR_MAX,
      .counter_dir  = TIMER_COUNT_UP,       //counts from 0 to counter value
      .auto_reload  = TIMER_AUTORELOAD_EN,  // reloads counter automatically
      .divider      = TIMER_DIVIDER
    };

    timer_idx_t       _timerIndex;
    timer_group_t     _timerGroup;
    uint32_t          interruptFlag;        // either TIMER_INTR_T0 or TIMER_INTR_T1
    
    uint8_t           _timerNo;

    esp32_timer_callback _callback;        // pointer to the callback function
    float             _frequency;       // Timer frequency
    uint64_t          _timerCount;      // count to activate timer
    
    //xQueueHandle      s_timer_queue;

  public:

    ESP32TimerInterrupt(const uint8_t& timerNo)
    {     
      _callback = NULL;
        
      if (timerNo < MAX_ESP32_NUM_TIMERS)
      {
        _timerNo  = timerNo;

#if USING_ESP32_C3_TIMERINTERRUPT

        // Always using TIMER_INTR_T0
        _timerIndex = (timer_idx_t)   ( (uint32_t) 0 );
        
        // timerNo == 0 => Group 0, timerNo == 1 => Group 1
        _timerGroup = (timer_group_t) ( (uint32_t) timerNo);
        
#else
      
        _timerIndex = (timer_idx_t)   (_timerNo % TIMER_MAX);
        
        _timerGroup = (timer_group_t) (_timerNo / TIMER_MAX);
        
#endif          
      }
      else
      {
        _timerNo  = MAX_ESP32_NUM_TIMERS;
      }
    };

    // frequency (in hertz) and duration (in milliseconds). Duration = 0 or not specified => run indefinitely
    // No params and duration now. To be addes in the future by adding similar functions here or to esp32-hal-timer.c
    bool setFrequency(const float& frequency, const esp32_timer_callback& callback)
    {
      if (_timerNo < MAX_ESP32_NUM_TIMERS)
      {      
        // select timer frequency is 1MHz for better accuracy. We don't use 16-bit prescaler for now.
        // Will use later if very low frequency is needed.
        _frequency  = TIMER_BASE_CLK / TIMER_DIVIDER;   //1000000;
        _timerCount = (uint64_t) _frequency / frequency;
        // count up

#if USING_ESP32_S2_TIMERINTERRUPT
        TISR_LOGWARN3(F("ESP32_S2_TimerInterrupt: _timerNo ="), _timerNo, F(", _fre ="), TIMER_BASE_CLK / TIMER_DIVIDER);
        TISR_LOGWARN3(F("TIMER_BASE_CLK ="), TIMER_BASE_CLK, F(", TIMER_DIVIDER ="), TIMER_DIVIDER);
        TISR_LOGWARN3(F("_timerIndex ="), _timerIndex, F(", _timerGroup ="), _timerGroup);
        TISR_LOGWARN3(F("_count ="), (uint32_t) (_timerCount >> 32) , F("-"), (uint32_t) (_timerCount));
        TISR_LOGWARN1(F("timer_set_alarm_value ="), TIMER_SCALE / frequency);
#elif USING_ESP32_S3_TIMERINTERRUPT
        // ESP32-S3 is embedded with four 54-bit general-purpose timers, which are based on 16-bit prescalers
        // and 54-bit auto-reload-capable up/down-timers
        TISR_LOGWARN3(F("ESP32_S3_TimerInterrupt: _timerNo ="), _timerNo, F(", _fre ="), TIMER_BASE_CLK / TIMER_DIVIDER);
        TISR_LOGWARN3(F("TIMER_BASE_CLK ="), TIMER_BASE_CLK, F(", TIMER_DIVIDER ="), TIMER_DIVIDER);
        TISR_LOGWARN3(F("_timerIndex ="), _timerIndex, F(", _timerGroup ="), _timerGroup);
        TISR_LOGWARN3(F("_count ="), (uint32_t) (_timerCount >> 32) , F("-"), (uint32_t) (_timerCount));
        TISR_LOGWARN1(F("timer_set_alarm_value ="), TIMER_SCALE / frequency);        
#else
        TISR_LOGWARN3(F("ESP32_TimerInterrupt: _timerNo ="), _timerNo, F(", _fre ="), TIMER_BASE_CLK / TIMER_DIVIDER);
        TISR_LOGWARN3(F("TIMER_BASE_CLK ="), TIMER_BASE_CLK, F(", TIMER_DIVIDER ="), TIMER_DIVIDER);
        TISR_LOGWARN3(F("_timerIndex ="), _timerIndex, F(", _timerGroup ="), _timerGroup);
        TISR_LOGWARN3(F("_count ="), (uint32_t) (_timerCount >> 32) , F("-"), (uint32_t) (_timerCount));
        TISR_LOGWARN1(F("timer_set_alarm_value ="), TIMER_SCALE / frequency);
#endif

        timer_init(_timerGroup, _timerIndex, &stdConfig);
        
        // Counter value to 0 => counting up to alarm value as .counter_dir == TIMER_COUNT_UP
        timer_set_counter_value(_timerGroup, _timerIndex , 0x00000000ULL);       
        
        timer_set_alarm_value(_timerGroup, _timerIndex, TIMER_SCALE / frequency);
               
        // enable interrupts for _timerGroup, _timerIndex
        timer_enable_intr(_timerGroup, _timerIndex);
        
        _callback = callback;
        
        // Register the ISR handler       
        // If the intr_alloc_flags value ESP_INTR_FLAG_IRAM is set, the handler function must be declared with IRAM_ATTR attribute
        // and can only call functions in IRAM or ROM. It cannot call other timer APIs.
       //timer_isr_register(_timerGroup, _timerIndex, _callback, (void *) (uint32_t) _timerNo, ESP_INTR_FLAG_IRAM, NULL);
        timer_isr_callback_add(_timerGroup, _timerIndex, _callback, (void *) (uint32_t) _timerNo, 0);

        timer_start(_timerGroup, _timerIndex);
  
        return true;
      }
      else
      {
#if USING_ESP32_C3_TIMERINTERRUPT
        TISR_LOGERROR(F("Error. Timer must be 0-1"));
#else      
        TISR_LOGERROR(F("Error. Timer must be 0-3"));
#endif
        
        return false;
      }
    }

    // interval (in microseconds) and duration (in milliseconds). Duration = 0 or not specified => run indefinitely
    // No params and duration now. To be addes in the future by adding similar functions here or to esp32-hal-timer.c
    bool setInterval(const unsigned long& interval, const esp32_timer_callback& callback)
    {
      return setFrequency((float) (1000000.0f / interval), callback);
    }

    bool attachInterrupt(const float& frequency, const esp32_timer_callback& callback)
    {
      return setFrequency(frequency, callback);
    }

    // interval (in microseconds) and duration (in milliseconds). Duration = 0 or not specified => run indefinitely
    // No params and duration now. To be addes in the future by adding similar functions here or to esp32-hal-timer.c
    bool attachInterruptInterval(const unsigned long& interval, const esp32_timer_callback& callback)
    {
      return setFrequency( (float) ( 1000000.0f / interval), callback);
    }

    void detachInterrupt()
    {
#if USING_ESP32_C3_TIMERINTERRUPT
      timer_group_intr_disable(_timerGroup, TIMER_INTR_T0);
#else    
      timer_group_intr_disable(_timerGroup, (_timerIndex == 0) ? TIMER_INTR_T0 : TIMER_INTR_T1);
#endif
    }

    void disableTimer()
    {
#if USING_ESP32_C3_TIMERINTERRUPT
      timer_group_intr_disable(_timerGroup, TIMER_INTR_T0);
#else    
      timer_group_intr_disable(_timerGroup, (_timerIndex == 0) ? TIMER_INTR_T0 : TIMER_INTR_T1);
#endif
    }

    // Duration (in milliseconds). Duration = 0 or not specified => run indefinitely
    void reattachInterrupt()
    {
#if USING_ESP32_C3_TIMERINTERRUPT
      timer_group_intr_enable(_timerGroup, TIMER_INTR_T0);
#else    
      timer_group_intr_enable(_timerGroup, (_timerIndex == 0) ? TIMER_INTR_T0 : TIMER_INTR_T1);
#endif    
    }

    // Duration (in milliseconds). Duration = 0 or not specified => run indefinitely
    void enableTimer()
    {
#if USING_ESP32_C3_TIMERINTERRUPT
      timer_group_intr_enable(_timerGroup, TIMER_INTR_T0);
#else    
      timer_group_intr_enable(_timerGroup, (_timerIndex == 0) ? TIMER_INTR_T0 : TIMER_INTR_T1);
#endif
    }

    // Just stop clock source, clear the count
    void stopTimer()
    {
      timer_pause(_timerGroup, _timerIndex);
    }

    // Just reconnect clock source, start current count from 0
    void restartTimer()
    {
      timer_set_counter_value(_timerGroup, _timerIndex , 0x00000000ULL);
      timer_start(_timerGroup, _timerIndex);
    }

    int8_t getTimer() __attribute__((always_inline))
    {
      return _timerIndex;
    };
    
    int8_t getTimerGroup() __attribute__((always_inline))
    {
      return _timerGroup;
    };

}; // class ESP32TimerInterrupt

#include "ESP32_ISR_Timer.hpp"

#endif    // ESP32TIMERINTERRUPT_HPP
```

INO file:

```
    // These define's must be placed at the beginning before #include "ESP32TimerInterrupt.h"
    #define _TIMERINTERRUPT_LOGLEVEL_  4
    #define HW_TIMER_INTERVAL_MS       1L
    #define NUMBER_ISR_TIMERS          2
    #define LED_TOGGLE_INTERVAL_MS     2000L
    #define BLOCKING_TIME_MS           10000L
    #define LED                        25
    
    long blockingTime;
    
    void doingSomething0(){}
    void doingSomething1(){}
    
    uint32_t TimerInterval[NUMBER_ISR_TIMERS] = {1000L,  1500L};
    typedef void (*irqCallback)();
    irqCallback irqCallbackFunc[NUMBER_ISR_TIMERS] = 
    {
      doingSomething0,  
      doingSomething1
    };
    
    // To be included only in main(), .ino with setup() to avoid `Multiple Definitions` Linker Error
    #include "ESP32TimerInterrupt.hpp"
    //#include "ESP32_ISR_Timer.h"
    //#include <SimpleTimer.h>              // https://github.com/jfturcot/SimpleTimer
    
    volatile uint32_t startMillis = 0;
    
    ESP32Timer ITimer(1);      // Init ESP32 timer 1
    ESP32_ISR_Timer ISR_Timer; // Init ESP32_ISR_Timer
    
    /************************************/
    bool IRAM_ATTR TimerHandler(void * timerNo)
    { 
      static int  timeRun  = 0;
    
      ISR_Timer.run();
    
      // Toggle LED every LED_TOGGLE_INTERVAL_MS = 2000ms = 2s
      if (++timeRun == (LED_TOGGLE_INTERVAL_MS / HW_TIMER_INTERVAL_MS))
      {
        timeRun = 0;
        //timer interrupt toggles pin LED_BUILTIN
        digitalWrite(LED, !digitalRead(LED));
      }
      return true;
    }
    /************************************/
    void setup()
    {
      Serial.begin(115200);
      while (!Serial);
    
      pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
      delay(200);
    
      Serial.print(F("\nStarting ISR_16_Timers_Array on ")); 
      Serial.println(ARDUINO_BOARD);
      Serial.print(ESP32_TIMER_INTERRUPT_VERSION);
      Serial.print(F(" runninr at CPU Frequency = ")); 
      Serial.print(F_CPU / 1000000); 
      Serial.println(F(" MHz"));
    
    // Interval in microsecs
      if (ITimer.attachInterruptInterval(HW_TIMER_INTERVAL_MS * 1000, TimerHandler))
      {
        startMillis = millis();
        Serial.print(F("Starting ITimer OK, millis() = ")); 
        Serial.println(startMillis);
      }
      else
        Serial.println(F("Can't set ITimer. Select another freq. or timer"));
    
    // You can use up to 16 timer for each ISR_Timer
      for (uint16_t i = 0; i < NUMBER_ISR_TIMERS; i++)
        ISR_Timer.setInterval(TimerInterval[i], irqCallbackFunc[i]); 
    }
    /************************************/
    void loop()
    {
      if ((millis() - blockingTime) < BLOCKING_TIME_MS)
        return;
      blockingTime = millis();
    }
```

Comment: Hi @user1511360 - please edit your question to include the full error messages, including the file and line number, rather than a description of the error messages. This will make it much easier for others to try to help you. As it is you're asking us to guess where they're coming from.

Comment: THIS IS THE COMPLETE ERROR MESSAGE

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am running into the same problem. Though I am using platformio...

Comment: Sorry, no. I switched the processor to arduino Nano Every.